# Is there a way to require Outlook users to include a location in meetings?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, meetings

We have a limited number of conference rooms available at my company. Our users rarely include a room in Outlook scheduled meetings, so there are often room conflicts. Is there any way to make filling out a location to be mandatory?

Comment: Not so much an answer, as Im unsure about making the location in the meeting invitation mandatory, I honestly think there isn't a way. But as a suggested solution to the problem, you could create an Office resource calendar that is shared (under public folders) and mandate that when people schedule something they both check that first, and add thier meeting to it when its placed. It may clear up some confusion and conflicts once people get used to using it.

Comment: A solution would be covertly sending some people for snack breaks in the rooms at common meeting hours. "Sorry, did you reserve a room?"

Answer (score 0):

Yup. This requires an Exchange Server Trasnport Rule. A quick Google shows that the "Condition" is a new Meeting Request, the Action is Block, and the Exception is "Location filled".